# Knowing distributions of X|Y and X find distribution of Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X|Y$ have normal distribution $\mathcal N(0,\frac{1}{2Y})$ and $X$ have Cauchy distribution $C(1)$. Find distribution of $Y$.

I don't know how to approach this kind of exercises. I tried to guess joint density function but with no results.

Comment: I think this question may require some educated guess. We know that $f_{X|Y=y}(x|y)f_Y(y) = f_{Y|X=x}(x)f_X(x)$ and we just  two of them are given. So I am not sure if the solution is a unique one. But the fact that the ratio of two independent normal random variables with zero mean and identical variance will follows the standard Cauchy distribution may help you to solve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more principled way of doing this, and you don't suggest the support of $p(y)$, but this is an educated guessing type approach to find some solution where I take the support of $Y$ to be $(0,\infty)$. We know that
$$
p(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty}p(x |y ) p(y) dy,
$$
and so
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{1/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-yx^2}p(y)dy \tag{1}
\end{align*}
this suggests we want to make a judicious choice of $p(y)$ so that the integrand of the expression is proportional to some recognisable class of distributions - preferably with normalising constant $\pi(1+x^2)$.

Now the fact that we have $1+x^2$ appearing in $(1)$ but only $x^2$ appearing in the argument of the exponential suggests that the choice
$$
p(y) = f(y)e^{-y}, \tag{2}
$$
for some choice of $f(y)$ will simplify things. After this substitution and rearranging $(1)$ we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)} =\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}y^{1/2}e^{-(1+x^2)y}f(y)dy \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Now we need to consider the class of distributions we are familiar with and pick some possible candidates. After letting $\beta = 1+x^2$ then $(3)$ has components that look similar to a Gamma distribution and infact we know that
$$
\int_0^{\infty} y^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\beta y} =\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\beta^{\alpha}} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{(1+x^2)^{\alpha}}, \tag{4}
$$
now on inspection it would be ideal if we could choose $f(y)$ such that $\alpha = 1$ in $(4)$. Which suggests that $f(y)y^{1/2} = 1$
$$
p(y) \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}e^{-y}, \qquad \mbox{or} \qquad p(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}y^{1/2 - 1}e^{-y},
$$
which is a $\mbox{Gamma}(1/2, 1)$ distribution. So unless I have made a mistake along the way that is one possible solution to your problem as posed - though there may be others?